# Getting SUM function to work in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to get something like this. These are all in minutes I guess it goes that way when I type them like this.

```
Number     Time     After Work      TOTAL
1          1:52       2:00         (Result Of Course)
2          3:54       2:00 
3
4
5
```

I'm trying to get to plus/add all the "time" plus "afterwork" divided by the number that has a registered value like 1 and 2. I don't know how to use excel (I don't know the terms or what the right formula is called).

I'm completely illiterate about this stuff and I really can't get through the formula explanations, tried couple of stuff but unfortunately failed that's why I'm here, hopefully I can get an answer right away

Comment: Sorry, it's really difficult to figure out what you're trying to do here. Could you try clarifying please?

Comment: Didn't Notice It Did Came Up Like This ,

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ag7d5eVAhJGCdEhhc0RBa3dSM2NFdWMtUjVMQU9nVkE&usp=sharing

I want to Add AVerage Handle To To After Call Work
And Divide It To The Numbers 1-10 And So On That Has A Value In alined To them Like
Number "1" AHT 17:00 ACW 2:00
So Add 17:00 And 2:00 Divided By 1 And So On TO Like
16:54 Add To 0:56 "Plus The First Total From Number "1" " Dvided By 2

Im sorry i couldnt think of any better explanations

Comment: @Jethro just some advice for the future. You don't need to right in sentence case for comments (capitals on each word).

Comment: @Jethro and your explanation still doesn't make sense. Now it sounds like you want an average, when your title says SUM. Can you possible provide an example of what you are trying to do, using hard values, rather then the ideal generated processed numbers? Put it into your question too!

Comment: @Fogest Sorry im just not really sure what should i call it, but
if its average ill go with the formula that you would give me,
also so its kinda like my ocd case were i dont feel comfortable typing words without starting it with capital haha.

The only thing that i could think of for the explanation is that, I Need To Add Up Two Things "The Handle Tim And & After Call" And Divide With The "Number Of Calls"

You Can Check The Link That Im WOrking On Right Now, I'm really sorry that this is the only explanation that i could give, i really dont know how to explain these stuff :(

Comment: I already tried the solution that was provided , again thanks, but if i need to merged 2 cells like B2-C2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Number is in `A2`, Time `B2`, after work in `C2` and the total in `D2`, put the following formula in `D2`

```
=(B2+C2)/A2
```

Copy the formula in `D2` to `D3`, `D4` etc

[Here's an example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AqK1oa8Jom_ddE9nc1RzS1J3cWJqTXdhVHgxbWZkYVE&usp=sharing)

Comment: What If I Merged To Cells ? How WOuld It Work out ?

Comment: I'm Also Trying to Get A Grand Total of all of those in one column , sorry about this :/

Comment: Should work, but you've got to use the cell with the value usually the first.

Comment: For total use =SUM(first_cell:last_cell)  I've updated my example

Comment: Alirght ! Thanks i see on your example while you're working on it, i'll let you know if i encounter problems, is there a way where i can like give Kudos or something like that in here ? man i really appreciate this

Comment: Done ! Really useful Thanks, https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ag7d5eVAhJGCdEhhc0RBa3dSM2NFdWMtUjVMQU9nVkE&hl=en#gid=0 Aside From that is there a way that i can get a grand total using This Form that i have to put it in " AHT AVERAGING " Without putting formulas in everybox ?

Comment: You'll need the calculation somewhere, but you can hide the column if you don't want it displayed.  The SUM formula can got anywhere

Comment: I'm not really sure how to hide it i cant see it on the sheet that you have

Comment: I've now hidden the totals column, click on the little triangle on the column and select hide column

Comment: Oh yeah F6 That's where you hide it, cool, can you pull it up again so i can see the formula that i have to put in there ?

Comment: Could i still like Put F3-F10 Even though F5-10 Doesn't Have A Value ?

Comment: Yes, it will just come out as 0

Comment: Sorry i had to bother you to do this, is there any site where i can get some tutorials for this ? or all of this should be self thought ?

Comment: It's just knowing spreadsheets, just search for "google spreadsheet tutorial"

Comment: Alright then, if i dont get those instructions , anyway that i could get a hold of you for some help ? :D

Comment: Not easily.  When you get to 20 rep, you could use the chat feature to reach me.

Comment: Alright then, well anyways i really thank you for this man and have good one !